# Add a place to google maps with node

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on a little project that I would allow me to update the location of a food truck that moves often.

I know there are apps that one could download but I'm hoping to avoid telling people to download ANOTHER app to keep up, instead it would be awesome to just have it searchable on google maps and have GPS directions to the truck available.

I see that the places API allows adding and deleting of places, I'm not sure how long that takes to update but I will figure that out once I can actually add a place.

Has anyone been able to succesfully do anything like this before with node? I understand that the javascript API will not do add requests so it seems node is the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the places API, Google said:

> When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps.

So your truck won't be visible on the Google Maps until after Google Maps decided to add it. But more than this, if you look at the deleting section:

> A place can only be deleted if:
>
> *The place was added by the application that is requesting the
>   deletion. 
>   *The place add request has not successfully passed through
>   the Google Maps moderation process, and the place is therefore visible
>   only to the application that added it.

Which is, in other words, you would not able to update its position ever again after they approved your location.

In stead, you should use the Javascript API to make your own webapp, to get something like this http://planefinder.net/flight/CPA872

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).